# android:--java.net.ProtocolException:Too many follow-up requests:21

Tags: android

I am trying to sync my app with the server (periodically,on-demand & when network outage happens),which uses the basic authentication for the syncing.Here i am facing this error.

Had done some research on this but found no solution.Have anyone come across this & have a solution???

PS:I am a novice developer in android.

Comment: Could you give us your code please ?

Comment: One reason that sync was failing was: the credentials to the server to sync from was changed/revocation is needed. In my case i am calling the correct URL but, the password was revoked and it is unknown to me. So, the http client was making retries for every 5 mins until it was success.So getting follow-up error.  In my code max retries was set to only 20. So after 20 retries it is posting exception for 21st time.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend double checking the method url that you are using. 
For instance, can you run it using  Postman or some other REST client and get a valid response? 
This behavior happened in one of my project while I accidentally used a broken method URL but with a right host. 
good luck:)